# please help me residual data points teacher is a no go

Tags: statistics

A theme park uses roller coaster riders on the “chute” as a predictor of the total number of visitors to purchase a souvenir when leaving the park.  There were 232 riders on the “chute” on a Saturday.  The statistical analysis predicted that there would be 200 riders.  Calculate the residual for that data point
I don't see how to solve it's like I have information missing but this is the entire question I have even asked my teacher. She just told me what I need is here and to follow the steps in order find the residual data points but how I can't even get the liner  model

Comment: The first sentence says that the number of riders on the chute is used as a predictor for another quantity, but in the actual question, the number of riders on the chute is predicted. Am I missing something or is the first sentence completely unrelated to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residual is the observed minus the expected, in this case $232-200=32$

You can't get a linear model until you have a load more data

Comment: It's honestly that simple

Comment: Yes that's it!.

Comment: Omg thank you I been looking at this way to  deep been on this  question for about four hours  trying to see if I'm missing something